# How can I override what happens when I click a file in Windows Explorer?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, filesystems, explorer

For example, if I want double left-click to open the file in one program (based on an algorithm), and double right-click to open the file in a different program.

Also, I'd like to override what happens when an external program tries to launch a (non-executable) file.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly advise that you do not override the way windows explorer works.  People are already familiar with the way it works, and changing it will cause people to do things they don't intend.

Changing the way something so important works, is a very very bad idea.

For technical reasons why this is a bad idea, see [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx).  I see by your profile that you have C++ skill, and i would suggest doing this in C++ rather than C#.

Comment: It would be bad if Microsoft drastically changed the way explorer worked in an update. I don't think it would be so bad if someone knowingly installed an extension. And anyway, for the most part I just want to make it so that if an unrecognized file type is being opened, it will look at the first few bytes of the file and try to make an educated guess based on that, like linux does, rather than hopelessly giving up and asking the user what to do. For the most part, things would operate the same.

Comment: Well, likewise, I would strongly suggest against doing it at all, but I would advise against doing it even more in C#.  The reason is that you want explorer extensions to be as small and simple as possible.  C# code carries with it the entire overhead of the CLI, which has to then be loaded into the process space of the explorer app.  What's more, you can't control if someone might have loaded an earlier version of the VM into that space as well, and that would be disasterous for your extension and the Explorer instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an easy task, but you can extend the shell or use system hooks:

1. Creating a Windows Shell Extension - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776797(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. I think that you won't be able to achieve exactly what you describe just with Shell Extensions. If you want to investigate further, then you have to start playing with system hooks. There are some projects where you can start looking at, before going to MSDN documentation:
   [Shell Extension with Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/smartmove.aspx)
   [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx)